# Interview - Android code

Tags: android

Iv'e been in an interview, what should be the wrong with the following ?

I can assume it's the issue that you can't have a check whether a class is null right ?!
Thanks !

```
public class NiceActivity extends Activity {

    private static AmazingClass a;

    class AmazingClass {
        int x;
        int y;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nice);
        if (a == null) {
            a = new AmazingClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it could make leak the activity

Comment: You could have a memory leak

Comment: plus the `a` amazing class is not necessarily singleton as expected(?) since it can be created multiple times on each `onCreate`

Comment: @Blackbelt why memory leak ?

Comment: because `a` is static, and it is a reference to a inner class which is not static, meaning it has an intrinsic reference to the activity

Comment: Ok, I get it. thx :)

Comment: Would the potential for a memory leak still exist if `AmazingClass` were not an inner class? i

Comment: No, as long as it has not a n explicit reference to the Activity.

Answer (score 4):

The inner class is not static, which may result in it outliving the activity while still having a reference to it. This may result in an activity leak.

This article explains this problem in more depth:
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html

Answer (score 1):

As the inner class AmazingClass is not static, each instance has an implicit reference to the outer class (NiceActivity).

The NiceActivity class has a reference to the AmazingClass and this reference is never cleared.

Therefore, the Activity will never be garbage collected and there will be a memory leak.

In a schema, that would roughly look like this:

```
root GC -1-> Activity class -2-> Amazing object -3-> Activity object
```

The reference number 2 or 3 need to be cleared to avoid such a leak.

Comment: In Java, non-static inner and anonymous classes hold an implicit reference to their outer class. Static inner classes, on the other hand, do not. What you have written is probably reverse.

Comment: That's what I meant, can you tell me which of the sentences is not clear ?

Comment: The NiceActivity class has a reference to the AmazingClass. This is what you have written. But I think you meant to say, The AmazingClass has a reference to the NiceActivity.